# SQL Group View Query and join with Other table

Tags: sql

`sqlstring = "Select PurchasesBody.ItemId, Items.Iteminfo, Sum(TTLQtyLose) As PurQty, Avg(PerUnitCost) AS AvgRate, Sum(TTLValue) AS NetValue From PurchasesBody left Join Items On PurchasesBody.ItemId=Items.ItemId Group By PurchasesBody.ItemId"`

When i Try to get Items.Iteminfo then error occurs. Can any one help where i am wrong..

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include columns in the SELECT list to the GROUP BY clause.

```
    Select PurchasesBody.ItemId, 
       Items.Iteminfo, Sum(TTLQtyLose) As PurQty, 
       Avg(PerUnitCost) AS AvgRate, Sum(TTLValue) AS NetValue 
     From PurchasesBody 
       left Join Items On PurchasesBody.ItemId=Items.ItemId 
     Group By PurchasesBody.ItemId,Items.Iteminfo
```

Comment: Column 'Items.ItemInfo' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either aggregate function or the Group By clause.

Comment: @DollyDimple when ever an aggregate function is used in a Select query,the other columns in the SELECT list should be included in the GROUP BY clause..